# Run-time error 13 in VBA for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

The scripts below bring up a Run-time error '13' Type mismatch if I have a value in AE49 or Z40 but then delete it. Ideally, if the value is deleted, it should 're hide' the rows (this is what I have attempted to achieve with the Case Else line).

```
Private Sub Script2(ByVal Target As Range)

    If (Not Intersect(Target, Range("Z40")) Is Nothing) Then

        Select Case Target.Value
            Case "PowerPoint", "Verbal"
                  Range("A41").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case Else
                  Range("A41").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Script3(ByVal Target As Range)

    If (Not Intersect(Target, Range("AE49")) Is Nothing) Then
       Select Case Target.Value
          Case 1
             Range("A50:A52").EntireRow.Hidden = False
             Range("A53:A55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
          Case 2
             Range("A50:A53").EntireRow.Hidden = False
             Range("A54:A55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
          Case 3
             Range("A50:A54").EntireRow.Hidden = False
             Range("A55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
          Case 4
             Range("A50:A55").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Case Else
             Range("A50:A55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What range are you passing as your argument in to your methods?

Comment: On which line, does the error show up?

Comment: If your `Target` range is more than 1 cell the `Case "PowerPoint", "Verbal"` line will throw you a `Run-time error '13': Type mismatch`.
Can you confirm that your `Target` is a single-cell Range only?

Comment: I'm sorry guys, but you've confused me here.  I don't know what line the error shows up on. I'm a VBA novice!

Comment: @KirtjE: If the error shows up, click on "Debug" button. That is the line on which the error is thrown. Can you paste that line?

Answer (score 0):

I believe is nothing applies to objects.

Try

```
if nz(yourRange, "") <> "" then
```

Comment: Where should this be included?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more specifically what you're trying to achieve, I'd us the WorkSheet_Change event:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

If (Not Intersect(Target, Range("Z40")) Is Nothing) Then
    If Target.Value <> "PowerPoint" And Target.Value <> "Verbal" Then
        Rows(41).Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows(41).Hidden = False
    End If
End If

If (Not Intersect(Target, Range("AE49")) Is Nothing) Then
    Select Case Target.Value
     Case 1
          Range("A50:A52").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A53:A55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 2
          Range("A50:A53").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A54:A55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 3
          Range("A50:A54").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 4
          Range("A50:A55").EntireRow.Hidden = False
       Case Else
          Range("A50:A55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End Select
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With
End Sub
```

Open the VBA IDE, double click the sheet you're like to run the code on and copy the entire block of code I posted above (you can omit the Option Explicit if you already have it set).  You can only have one Worksheet_Change event per sheet, so if you're already using that event, you'll have to post that code and we can try and merge the two.

Comment: I'm using Worksheet_Change to call the other scripts.

Comment: @KirtjE perfect!  My code replaces both your worksheet change event and your scripts.